# Restoring checkpoint failed: Key not found in checkpoint

Tags: tensorflow

I'm able to successfully train a RNN and see accuracy/loss appear in Tensorboard. The problem is that when I try to load the model from a checkpoint file, I'm getting the following error:

```
Key fully_connected/Variable not found in checkpoint
     [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at train.py:87)  = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Here is the code that is causing the issue (I omitted parts that I thought were irrelevant):

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

with tf.name_scope('input_data'):
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batchSize, maxSeqLength])

with tf.name_scope('labels'):
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numClasses])

with tf.name_scope('embeddings'):
    data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(wordVectors, input_data)

with tf.name_scope('lstm_layer'):
    lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstmUnits)
    lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstmCell, output_keep_prob=0.75)

with tf.name_scope('rnn_feed_forward'):
    value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, data, dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.name_scope('fully_connected'):
    weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([lstmUnits, numClasses]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[numClasses]))

with tf.name_scope('predictions'):
    value = tf.transpose(value, [1, 0, 2])
    last = tf.gather(value, int(value.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
    prediction = (tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)

with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    correctPred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(labels,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPred, tf.float32))

with tf.name_scope('cost'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=labels))

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

saver = tf.train.Saver() # Saving and loading

# Train the model
print('Training has begun.')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    tf.summary.scalar('Loss', loss)
    tf.summary.scalar('Accuracy', accuracy)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir, sess.graph)

    for i in range(iterations):
        nextBatch, nextBatchLabels = get_train_batch();
        sess.run(optimizer, { input_data: nextBatch, labels: nextBatchLabels })

        if (i % 50 == 0):
            print('Entering iteration ' + str(i))
            summary = sess.run(merged, {input_data: nextBatch, labels: nextBatchLabels})
            writer.add_summary(summary, i)

        if (i % 10000 == 0 and i != 0):
            save_path = saver.save(sess, modelsDir, global_step=i)
            print('Saved to %s' % save_path)
    writer.close()
```

My was that when I added the optimizer to the session with `sess.run(optimizer...` I was effectively adding all of the variables and their dependency variables to the graph.

The key "fully_connected" though is a name_scope, and I'm a little confused as to how it was randomly left out.

### Details

The output to the `chkp.print_tensors_in_checkpoint_file("./models/pretrained_lstm.ckpt-10000", tensor_name='', all_tensors=True)` command gives me a bunch of variables with names that aren't very useful:

```
Variable
Variable_1
Variable_1/Adam
Variable_1/Adam_1
etc.
```

Now I'm wondering if this is related to me not explicitly naming variables? Trying that now.

### Questions

1. Does anybody with more experience spot what I did wrong? Could you enlighten me please?
2. As an open-ended question, what tools besides Tensorboard (which didn't help me solve this issue because it isn't actually reading the checkpoint files), would you recommend for inspecting sessions and graphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong. Adam optimizer combines AdaGrad (Adaptive Gradient) and RMSProp(Root Mean Square Propagation) techniques. The latter keeps track of per-parameter learning rates, which are adapted based on the moving average of current gradients.

What is important in case of restoring models, is that the algorithm uses EMA of the gradient and the squared gradient, hence internal variables beta1 and beta2, which control decay rates, added to the layers.

You can simply not restore these particular variables by excluding them from the dictionary, which you can pass to `saver.restore` 
You can create this dict

```
vars_to_restore = [i[0] for i in tf.train.list_variables(file.ckpt)]
restore_dict = {variable.op.name: variable for variable in tf.global_variables() if variable.op.name in vars_to_restore}
```

Then you just need to initialize adam variables

```
tf.variables_initializer(optimizer.variables())
```

You can use this simple functions to check variables/scope names in checkpoint and current graph.